# Find how many times it took to achieve a particular outcome in SQL Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to find out how many attempts it takes to achieve an outcome from a SQL table. For example My table contains CustomerID, Outcome, OutcomeType. The outcome I am looking for is Sale

So if I had this record:

```
CID   Outcome  OutcomeID   Date
1    No Answer     0       01/01/2015 08:00:00
1    No Interest   0       02/01/2015 09:00:00
1    Sale          1       02/02/2015 10:00:00
1    Follow up     2       03/02/2015 10:00:00
```

I can see it took 2 attempts to get a sale. I need to do this for all the customers in a table which contains thousands of entries. They may have entries after the sale and I need to exclude these, they may also have additional sales after the first but I  am only interested in the first sale.

i hope this is enough info,

many thanks in advance

Edit as requested, the outcome I would look for would be:

```
CID   CountToOutcome
1         2  
2         3   
3         5
```

etc

Comment: Tried doing a row_Number() then max on row_number() where outcomeid = 1 then a subtract, but applying filters affect the rownumber.

Comment: An example of the expected data output would also help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with window functions and aggregation:

```
select cid,
       min(case when Outcome = 'Sale' then seqnum end) - 1 as AttemptsBeforeSale
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by cid order by date) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by cid;
```

Note:  This provides the value for the *first* sale for each `cid`.

Comment: This works for me, many thanks sir! I will need to study this in depth to get a full understanding